# Data Locality in Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, kubernetes, hdfs

Do we need HDFS or S3 when running Spark on Kubernetes?
Will data locality be that efficient if we use just NFS storage type?

Or maybe there is something fundamentally wrong in my understanding of Spark on Kubernetes.

Comment: NFS doesn't know how to split files, like the HDFS or S3 Spark reader do, so the answer depends on how large your files really are

Comment: @OneCricketeer that point is fair when we have to read from HDFS. but there are couple of points here
1. In your case, there should be no difference running HDFS external or in K8s
2. If my source data is not in HDFS then just for writing I won't need it, right? as spark will take care of correct partitioning.

Comment: If the data is small enough (less than 256MB per file), I'd estimate the difference is minimal, yes. I've not personally tested this, however. To truly get data locality, though, you'd also need YARN (via Yunikorn project). If your data source is not a filesystem, such as reading from a database or Kafka, then the only other consideration would be network latency for external cluster communication

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If you are working externally with data(HDFS/S3), then you won't have data locality and performance won't be awesome.

You can [run hdfs inside Kubernetes](https://databricks.com/session/hdfs-on-kubernetes-lessons-learned) to try and avoid this issue.

Comment: MinIO or Hadoop Ozone are better options than running HDFS in k8s

Comment: No no, I know I can run hdfs in k8s. But does it give me more efficiency when I run spark in k8s? By the way the video you sent guys did great job. But they don't update their repo since 2 years, so it's quite outdated.